# How to sum column in reverse order in pandas with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I currently need to replicate this dataset where I must groupby subjectID copy and count how many have a score of 1 in the future.  I must count them in reverse basically however I'm not sure how to do that and groupby subject ID at the same time.

```
   SubjectID copy  Score  Number of All Future Hosp for O column
0        phchp003      1                                       4
1        phchp003      1                                       3
2        phchp003      1                                       2
3        phchp003      1                                       1
4        phchp003      1                                       0
5        phchp004      1                                       4
6        phchp004      1                                       3
7        phchp004      1                                       2
8        phchp004      1                                       1
9        phchp004      1                                       0
10       phchp006      0                                       3
11       phchp006      0                                       3
12       phchp006      0                                       3
13       phchp006      0                                       3
14       phchp006      1                                       2
15       phchp006      1                                       1
16       phchp006      1                                       0
```

I currently have

```
data['Sum']= data.groupby(['SubjectID copy'])['Score'].cumsum()
```

which gives me the values but summed in descending order, where I need mine to go from bottom up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) to reverse before using [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html). We can then use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to only consider "future" values:

```
data['Sum'] = (
    data.loc[::-1]  # Reverse DataFrame
        .groupby(['SubjectID copy'])['Score']  # Groups
        .transform(lambda s: s.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())  # handle transformation
)
```

`data`:

```
   SubjectID copy  Score  Sum
0        phchp003      1    4
1        phchp003      1    3
2        phchp003      1    2
3        phchp003      1    1
4        phchp003      1    0
5        phchp004      1    4
6        phchp004      1    3
7        phchp004      1    2
8        phchp004      1    1
9        phchp004      1    0
10       phchp006      0    3
11       phchp006      0    3
12       phchp006      0    3
13       phchp006      0    3
14       phchp006      1    2
15       phchp006      1    1
16       phchp006      1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

To find how many `1`s come in the future `transform` the group `sum` and subtract off the `cumsum`.

```
df['Sum'] = (df.groupby('SubjectID copy')['Score'].transform('sum')
             - df.groupby('SubjectID copy')['Score'].cumsum())

   SubjectID copy  Score  Sum
0        phchp003      1    4
1        phchp003      1    3
2        phchp003      1    2
3        phchp003      1    1
4        phchp003      1    0
5        phchp004      1    4
6        phchp004      1    3
7        phchp004      1    2
8        phchp004      1    1
9        phchp004      1    0
10       phchp006      0    3
11       phchp006      0    3
12       phchp006      0    3
13       phchp006      0    3
14       phchp006      1    2
15       phchp006      1    1
16       phchp006      1    0
```